# Moving SVG arrowhead needs correct orientation

Tags: animation, svg, path, orientation, marker

I'm looking for a way to properly orient an arrowhead that's animated to move along a defined path (bezier curve in this case). In this case the arrowhead must point downwards in the beginning and upwards at the end. This is to show the user how an object flows from one to another end. I'm halfway there but need help to correct the code I have which is given below. The correct orientation is shown in the static part of the SVG. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 105 140">
<path d="M10,10 C15,50 95,50 100,10" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" fill="none" id="wire" />
<!-- acceptable movement along the path but incorrect orientation -->
<polygon points="0,0 10,5 0,10 3,5" fill="red">
    <animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite">
        <mpath xlink:href="#wire" />
    </animateMotion>
</polygon>

<!-- Correctly oriented -->
<defs>
    <marker viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="3" refY="5" id="redArrowhead" orient="auto">
        <polygon points="0,0 10,5 0,10 3,5" fill="red" />
    </marker>
</defs>
<g stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" fill="none" transform="translate(0,30)">
    <path d="M10,10 C15,50 95,50 100,10" marker-start="url(#redArrowhead)" marker-end="url(#redArrowhead)" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add rotate="auto"

I also added a translate transform to keep the arrowhead on the line.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 105 140">
<path d="M10,10 C15,50 95,50 100,10" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" fill="none" id="wire" />
<!-- acceptable movement along the path but incorrect orientation -->
<polygon transform="translate(0,-6)" points="0,0 10,5 0,10 3,5" fill="red">
    <animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
        <mpath xlink:href="#wire" />
    </animateMotion>
</polygon>

<!-- Correctly oriented -->
<defs>
    <marker viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="3" refY="5" id="redArrowhead" orient="auto">
        <polygon points="0,0 10,5 0,10 3,5" fill="red" />
    </marker>
</defs>
<g stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" fill="none" transform="translate(0,30)">
    <path d="M10,10 C15,50 95,50 100,10" marker-start="url(#redArrowhead)" marker-end="url(#redArrowhead)" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you very much, the best answer I could imagine for this.

Comment: I thought I could do the rest to animate the whole arrow but apparently my knowledge is short and not sure which will work right.